# Php throws [caching_sha2_password] authetication error for RDS Mysql instance, even when authentication method is mysql_native_password

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, amazon-rds

On trying to connect to my MySQL instance via **PHPMyAdmin** it throws  ***mysqli::real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]***
and
***mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client***

Now here's the problem:

1. My default authentication method is NOT **caching_sha2_password** but as checked from **my.cnf.** file, it's already **mysql_native_password**
2. As suggested in many solutions elsewhere, I've also tried 'ALTER USER 'myuser'@'rds-endpoint' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'newpassword'; - Still no result. ( I think because it's already mysql_native_password)
3. I've also tried creating a new user, no result.
4. Many have pointed out that this is issue for MySQL 8.x which supports caching_sha2_password as new authentication. I've tried multiple combinations - MYSQL 7.x to all the way back to 5.x  as my RDS instances. **All of them yield same error**
5. It has also been mentioned in many places that issue gets fixed with PHP 7.x (PHP 7.4.x to be precise). I've tried that too - PHP 4.x to 7.x - **All same error.**
6. Leaving AWS RDS out of the picture, I've also tried setting up a new user@localhost and connecting it via PhpMyAdmin - **even in that case it gives same error.**
7. Also would like to note - issue is definitely not with RDS - just connecting to the DB from console via **mysql -h (or localhost) -u -p** works perfectly fine.
8. PHP config.php :

```
    /* Authentication type */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    /* Server parameters */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '*<RDS ENDPOINT>*.amazonaws.com';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '<username>';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '<password>';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '<username>';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: You say you've tried everything back to PHP 4.x and it gives the same error. But `mysqli` wasn't introduced until PHP 5.0. So maybe there's something wrong with how you're changing the version of PHP? Don't know if this is what's causing your problem, but it's a bit of a red flag.

Comment: @GregSchmidt as to how I'm changing the version - I'm not changing them live per se; every time I'm totally dropping off the ec2 linux instance and spawning a new one, then installing php in it - for a 'start from scratch' approach so that I don't mess it up. 
 In the new instance, post-installing php, mysql-server.x86_64, httpd, and php-mysqlnd.x86_64 I'm wget'ing phpMyAdmin from : https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz

Am I missing anything in this approach?

Comment: Not how I've ever set things up, so I don't know. Just pointing out that there should not be any way to get a `mysqli::real_connect()` error message with PHP4.x, as `mysqli` didn't exist then.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Sure, I get that. Leave php 4.x. This is happening with latest PHP version as well.